# How to get coordinate system info from shapefile using GDAL/OGR?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, coordinate-system, ogr, c++

GDAL version 2.1.1

If I open a geospatial raster file, such as a GeoTIFF or DTED file, with GDAL, then I can get the coordinate system info for that file, as a string in OpenGIS WKT format.  For example:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

The C++ code I use to get that info is simple and straightforward.

```
string path = "somewhere.dt1";
unsigned int openFlags = GA_ReadOnly;
GDALDataset * pDataset = static_cast<GDALDataset *>( GDALOpenEx(
    path.c_str(),
    openFlags,
    NULL, NULL, NULL ) );

string projWkt = pDataset->GetProjectionRef();

OGRSpatialReference srs( projWkt.c_str() );
srs.dumpReadable();
```

However, when I open a geospatial vector file, such as a shapefile, with GDAL, I get only a blank string for the coordinate system info.  The only difference in the C++ code I use is that I must also provide the `GDAL_OF_VECTOR` flag to `GDALOpenEx()`.

```
string path = "elsewhere.shp";
unsigned int openFlags = GA_ReadOnly | GDAL_OF_VECTOR;
GDALDataset * pDataset = static_cast<GDALDataset *>( GDALOpenEx(
    path.c_str(),
    openFlags,
    NULL, NULL, NULL ) );
```

The shapefile I am opening does have a valid coordinate system.  I can confirm that by opening the shapefile in ArcMap or ArcCatalog.  Both of those apps are able to tell me the coordinate system and projection info.

So, why am I not able to fetch it via this GDAL API?

Is there a different mechanism for vector files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a different mechanism for vector files?

Yes.  Although the vector and raster drivers [were merged in GDAL 2x](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc46_gdal_ogr_unification), you still need to know which methods apply to rasters and which are for vectors. Confusingly, vector datasources now expose methods that only apply to rasters...

The `GetProjectionRef` method you are using applies to raster datasources and you need to use the vector method `GetSpatialRef` (which returns a spatial reference object, not WKT...).

This works for vector (python code):

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

f = r'/path/to/shapefile.shp'

ds = gdal.OpenEx(f, gdal.OF_VECTOR) #gdal.OF_VECTOR is not required, but speeds things up as only vector drivers are tried
print('"%s"'%ds.GetLayer().GetSpatialRef().ExportToWkt())
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer from @Luke, the following is my C++ implementation.

I detect whether the file is raster or vector, using a utility function mentioned in [another post also answered by @Luke](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215157/why-does-gdal-open-a-dted-file-as-a-vector-format/215373#215373).

```
string path = "elsewhere.shp";
Format::Enum format = GetFileFormat( path );
```

I open the file.

```
GDALDataset * pDataset = NULL;
if ( format == Format::RASTER )
{
  unsigned int openFlags = GA_ReadOnly;
  pDataset = static_cast<GDALDataset *>( GDALOpenEx( inPath.c_str(), openFlags, NULL, NULL, NULL ) );
}
else if ( format == Format::VECTOR )
{
  unsigned int openFlags = GA_ReadOnly | GDAL_OF_VECTOR;
  pDataset = static_cast<GDALDataset *>( GDALOpenEx( inPath.c_str(), openFlags, NULL, NULL, NULL ) );
}
```

I get the spatial reference system for the file.

```
OGRSpatialReference srs;
if ( format == Format::RASTER )
{
  char const * szWkt = pDataset->GetProjectionRef();
  srs.importFromWkt( (char **)( &szWkt ) );
}
else if ( format == Format::VECTOR )
{
  // Assume just one vector layer in the dataset for now.
  OGRSpatialReference * pOrigSrs = pDataset->GetLayer( 0 )->GetSpatialRef();
  if ( pOrigSrs )
  {
    srs = *pOrigSrs;
  }
}
```

Now I can get what I want from the spatial reference system.

```
if ( srs.IsProjected() )
{
  ...
}
```